# Comparison between optimal binary search tree and AVL Trees?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm, avl-tree

I was preparing for my finals and while going through these topics, I got stuck with few queries.

I know that optimal binary Search trees give optimal structure to trees with respect to the frequency of the nodes. The idea is to keep the nodes having higher frequency (and also satisfying the bst properties) at the top for optimal solution.

Whereas Avl are BST which on rotation perform balancing and hence provide a balanced tree but frequencies don't play a role here.

So, my query is if we know that for frequencies of the respective nodes, we come to a optimal bst structure which is of the form :
 Eg :

```
10
  \
   12
     \
      14
        \
         16...And so on
```

I.e., linked list kind of a structure but it is optimal as frequencies are, for example [15,13,10,4,2..]

But if this is solved with AVL, AVL will balance the tree and form a different structure making it not so optimal for these frequencies.
So, my question is if we know the respective frequencies for the nodes, then applying AVL on such data is not the right choice as compared to optimal binary search tree ?
Is optimal binary search tree a better choice in such situations ?

I would be thankful if anyone can clear this doubt of mine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Optimal search trees are almost never useful because you'll seldom be able to predict query frequencies in advance. Even if you can, an AVL tree with a billion nodes has a worst case height of about 44. So finding any element requires 43 pointer traversals, maybe 170 instructions on a modern processor. An optimal tree might cut that to 4 under perfect conditions.  An application where 166 instructions is an important performance difference per lookup will be very hard to find. They exist, but they're very rare.

Comment: Alright. I agree that in real life application, prediction of frequencies in advance would be a very rare scenario. So, you mean to say optimal binary search tree are not that useful for modern processor considering modern day processor's better performance. Also, creation of billion of nodes with balancing would be slow with avl

Comment: If you ever need to create an AVL tree with a billion inserts and no deletions, then, yes, it _might_ be faster to sort the data and build the tree without re-balancing as you go. (Re-balancing is pretty cheap, so the difference could be pretty small.) But, again, this is a very rare scenario. The beauty of general purpose data structures is that 98% of the time they're usable without detailed performance considerations.That's why it virtually always pays to implement with the simplest method (e.g. building the tree with normal inserts) first, then optimize _after_ you find bottlenecks.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the detailed​ explanation. Really helpful.